# GDB: How to print the real object and all members of a pointer?

Tags: c++, gdb

**How can I print the real object and values of a pointer and its values in GDB?**

Assume I have a pointer to a base class `test`, and then assign it an instance of `test2`, how do I make this visible in GDB?

If I place a breakpoint at `delete` (line 20) of the following snippet an do:

```
break 20
Set print object on
run
```

Then I get:

```
(gdb) print *myTest
$1 = {p = 1, q = 2}
(gdb) display *myTest
1: *myTest = {p = 1, q = 2}
```

But what I expect (want to know) is the **class type**, and also the **output**  of `r`.

```
(gdb) print *myTest
$1 = {p = 1, q = 2, r = 3} **OF TYPE Test2**
(gdb) display *myTest
1: *myTest = {p = 1, q = 2, r = 3} **OF TYPE Test2**
```

How to get something like this?

**SNIPPET:**

```cpp
class test {
   private:
        int p = 1;
   protected:
        int q = 1;
};

class test2 : public test {
   private:
       int r = 3;
   public:
       test2() {
           q = 2;
       }
};

int main() {
   test* myTest = new test2();
   delete myTest;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The structures you have are not polymorphic, and there's no run-time information about possible parent classes. All GDB really knows is the type of the variable `myTest` which is `test*`.

Comment: If you want to access `*myTest` as a `test2` object, the only solution is to do what you would need to do in the code itself: Downcast. As in `print *(test2*) myTest` Of course, this relies on the fact that you *know* the "real" type of the object.

Comment: Isn't this `delete` UB if the base class doesn't have a virtual destructor? Also, with a virtual destructor, `set print object on` will to what you want.